# Picketlink single logout from IDP

Tags: jboss7.x, single-sign-on, java-ee-6

I am using Picketlink to achieve SSO between two applications (one is IDP and one is service provider). I am dealing with problem about logout for two days. Applications are running on Jboss 7.1.1.
So, the scenario is as follows:

1. I login to my IDP, index page of IDP app is shown. Ok, as expected.
2. I try to access some page in service provider application. Ok, login
   page didn't appear (because I am logged in to IDP), and requested
   page is shown. As expected.
3. Now I hit logout button in my IDP app, session is invalidated and I
   am logged out from IDP. As expected.
4. Now if I try to access some page in service provider app, this page
   is shown without login screen. This behaviour is unexpected for me
   because I want to be redirected again to IDP login page.

Picketlink documentation is very obscure and I can't find if that behaviour is expected. Does anyone know if this is Picketlink default behaviour or I have configuration problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it isn't a expected behavior, probably you missed some configuration detail.

Show your configuration files.
I guess you get a more quick reply asking it on https://community.jboss.org.

Take a look on picketlink quickstarts: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts

Answer (score 0):

In SSO there will be two sessions created one session which is created in your IDP and one more in your SP.If you logout from your IDP that session will be invalidated but the session in your SP is still alive.So still you can use services in your SP unless or until you are requesting your IDP to check for session.This comes when you refresh your page you will be redirected to your login page.If you are not refreshing your page and still working on SP you won't be redirected.

Make sure you are giving GLO=true when you logout and also check for the picketlink versions you are using.If you are going with one service provider then there won't be any problem but if you are going with more than one service provider then you need to use version  2.6.0.CR1 and beyond.Please refer https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/PLINK/Unsolicited+Responses for further details.

I would suggest you to download SAML chrome extension which will be very useful for checking SAML request and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Try make the logout using GLO=true parameter in the URL
This doc maybe help.
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/PLINK/Single+Logout